# Getting an error while using bulk_create() method of Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to bulk create some entries using `bulk_create()` method of **Django** in the DB table. On the final step where I'm passing the created list over there getting an error `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'` and due to this obviously no records are getting saved.

Below is the code through which I'm trying to save the records in the DB table.

> Class method

```
@classmethod
def mark_all_added(cls, id: int, spec_id: int) -> None:
    spec_ids = set(
        cls.objects.filter(spec_id=spec_id)
        .values_list("id")
    )

    through_objects = [
        cls.added_by.through(id=id, spec_id=sid)
        for sid in spec_ids
    ]

    cls.added_by.through.objects.bulk_create(through_objects) # getting error on this line
```

Could someone please help in highlighting my mistake or tell me how to resolve this issue while saving bulk records. I know I have a done a silly mistake but am unable to trace it. Any kind of would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide the *full* traceback?

Comment: It is a little difficult for me to add the full traceback as there is a lot of information that is visible related to the project. Even the above code is a sanitised one.

Comment: Are you sure there is no trailing comma at the line `cls.added_by.through(id=id, spec_id=sid)`? so `cls.added_by.through(id=id, spec_id=sid),`.

Comment: Yes I'm 100% sure there is no comma

Comment: nvm, I found it, you should make a "flat" `values_list`, it thus turns out you provided enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a *flat* list of `'id'`s, not a `QuerySet` of singleton tuples, by specifying `flat=True` in the [**`.values_list(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list), so:

```
@classmethod
def mark_all_added(cls, id: int, spec_id: int) -> None:
    spec_ids = set(
        cls.objects.filter(spec_id=spec_id)
        .values_list('id', flat=True)  # ← use flat=True
    )
    # …
```

Comment: Wow, must say you have eagle eyes. Brilliant and awesome you are it perfectly worked for me that was the only mistake. Bingo thank you so much for your help.